# Why are right floated elements affecting left floated elements?

Tags: html, css

Right float is affecting left float by pushing it below one before right floated element... I know this is a thing in all browsers, but I just can't wrap my head around this. Why is this a thing? Is this a backward compatibly thing or a bug in all browsers (checked Firefox, IE, Edge, Chrome). Do some specs actually demand this behaviour?

Basic CSS (tables are grey, left float is yellow, right float wrapper has a green border):

```
table {
    float: right;
    clear: right;
}
div.right {
    float: right;
    clear: right;
}
div.left {
    float: left;
    width: 10em;
}
```

Full code:
http://jsbin.com/deyejit/edit?html,css,output

[image]

Note. This is not a philosophical question ;-). I'm looking for actual reasoning and algorithm behind this.

Answer (score 0):

Notice how removing `clear: right` "fixes" the alignment issue. When you have a second right-floated element, you're clearing the right-float and this means that any subsequent floated elements - left *or* right - will appear below the element you have cleared.

Seems simple enough :D

The "wrapper" solution fixes this because you no longer have any `clear: right` elements before your left-floated box.

Comment: That would be a non issue if it would be `clear:left`. Why would `clear:right` affect `float:left`? It is meant to clear on `float:right` elements. I'm not using `clear:both`.